# R language auto Concat the multiple newly added columns

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have the following data frame, I want to concat the columns of item with their quanity. The new items with genertic or brand item name added everyday as a new columns with their quantity. I want to detect all the items in R language and their quantity automatically and want to concat into to mentioned expected output.

```
id    date        item_>>1_generic  item_>>1_brand    item_>>2_generic  item_>>2_brand  quantity_>>1_daily  quantity_>>2_daily
z1   2022-02-28   NA                name1             name11            NA                10                  20
z1   2021-10-31   name2             NA                name21            NA                10m                 20m
z2   2021-12-31   NA                name3             name31            NA                20mg                20
r3   2021-10-31   name4             NA                name41            NA                40                  50
r4   2021-06-30   NA                name5             NA                name51            50                  60
r5   2021-08-31   name6             NA                NA                name61            10                  30
```

My expected output is:

```
id    date         item1_quanity   item2_quanity
z1   2022-02-28   name1_10         name11_20 
z1   2021-10-31   name2_10m        name21_20m       
z2   2021-12-31   name3_20mg       name31_20
r3   2021-10-31   name4_40         name41_50        
r4   2021-06-30   name5_50         name51_60
r5   2021-08-31   name6_10         name61_30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df %>%
  rename_with(~str_remove(., '>>')) %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(id, date), names_to = c('item','num', '.value'), 
               names_sep = '_') %>%
  group_by(id, date, num) %>%
  mutate(generic = coalesce(generic, brand), 
         daily = na.omit(daily)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(generic)) %>%
  mutate(generic = str_c(generic, daily, sep = '_')) %>%
  select(-brand, -daily) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = c(item, num), values_from = generic,)

# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   id, date [6]
  id    date       item_1     item_2    
  <chr> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>     
1 z1    2022-02-28 name1_10   name11_20 
2 z1    2021-10-31 name2_10m  name21_20m
3 z2    2021-12-31 name3_20mg name31_20 
4 r3    2021-10-31 name4_40   name41_50 
5 r4    2021-06-30 name5_50   name51_60 
6 r5    2021-08-31 name6_10   name61_30
```

Comment: I want to add one more case like, for any item if the quantity column is num/float? 
I got an error while doing this:
`Can't combine item__8_>>_GENERIC <character> and item__8_>>_quantity <double>.`

Comment: @Irbaz inside the `pivot_longer` function include `values_transform = as.character` ie `pivot_longer(....., values_transform = as.character)`

Comment: In original data I have about 15 items so there is alot of column while running the script I got the following error: 
`Error in `stop_vctrs()`:
! Can't recycle ..1 (size 692100) to match ..3 (size 0).`
Is there any method I can avoid this?

Comment: @Irbaz can you run each line and tell me where there is an error

Comment: While running code line by line I got error on the following line:
`df %>% mutate(GENERIC = coalesce(GENERIC, BRAND), DAILY= na.omit(DAILY))`
ERROR:
`! Problem while computing DAILY = na.omit(DAILY).
x DAILY must be size 1, not 0.`

Comment: The daily column can be NA.

Comment: @Irbaz good. Then you should do `daily = if(all(is.na(daily))) NA else na.omit(daily)`

Comment: got the error on same line again:
 Problem while computing `DAILY = if (all(is.na(DAILY))) NA else
  na.omit(DAILY)`.
`DAILY must be size 3 or 1, not 2.`

Comment: @Irbaz `daily = if(all(is.na(daily))) NA else first(na.omit(daily))`

Comment: sometime the code run on this line ` meds %>%  pivot_longer(-c(ID, DATE), names_to = c('item','num', '.value'), 
               names_sep = '__', values_transform = as.character)` but mostly I am getting this error:
`Error in stop_vctrs():
! Can't recycle ..1 (size 692100) to match ..3 (size 0).`